# Copy a DB2 row to history table with a trigger (contains XML)

Tags: xml, triggers, db2

I want to copy a row that contains an XML column to a history table. Seems it is not possible to do that?!

What I have tried:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MARTIN."Pages_I" BEFORE UPDATE OF "tstamp" ON MARTIN."Pages" REFERENCING OLD AS old_row FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL SECURED
INSERT INTO "MARTIN"."HistoryPages" VALUES (old_row."pageId", (SELECT "pageXML" FROM "MARTIN"."Pages" WHERE "pageId" = old_row."pageId" LIMIT 1), old_row."tstamp");
```

=> not allowed due to INSERT in BEFORE trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER MARTIN."Pages_I" AFTER UPDATE OF "tstamp" ON MARTIN."Pages" REFERENCING OLD AS old_row FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL SECURED
INSERT INTO "MARTIN"."HistoryPages" VALUES (old_row."pageId", old_row."pageXML", old_row."tstamp");
```

=> can't reference old_row."pageXML" because it's a xml column

Is there any solution to this dilemma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no solution to this, it's just a limitation of the database system.